# Excel: How to keep ASCII numbers within a certain range?

Tags: excel, ascii

Basically, I need to keep some ASCII numbers within the range of capital letters only.

My program has many characters, that are then being converted into ASCII code. I am then adding a random number between -5 and 5 to this ASCII code and then converting it back to character form. Although, if the character is Z (ASCII code 90), I do not want it to convert into a symbol. It will somehow need to start back at 65 (being A).

Same goes if the character is A (ASCII code 65) and -5 is applied.

I honestly have no idea how to do this. Had a crack at it with a simple `if` statement, but I kept getting errors.

Here is how my sheet looks:

```
              A              B         C
      ______________________________________
   1 |  random-number   |  Letter |  ASCII
   2 |                  |    Z    |    90
   3 |                  |    A    |    80
   4 |                  |    T    |    84
   5 |                  |    V    |    86
   6 |                  |    W    |    87
   7 |                  |    E    |    69
```

If the `random-number` is equal to 5, each number within the `ASCII` column will be added by 5, and then converted back to character form in another cell somewhere.

Basically, in simple terms, if the ASCII code equals 65, make it equal 90 (if it equals one before A, make it equal Z), and if the ASCII code equals 91, make it equal 65 (if equals one after Z, make it equal A).

Comment: I can give you a macro that does it but i think it's achievable with a formula

Comment: @pnuts - Unfortunately, no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this macro to automate the entire process so run in on a new workbook to test it.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim i As Long

    Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "0"
    Range("A1") = "random number"
    Range("B1") = "letter"
    Range("C1") = "ASCII"
    Range("D1") = "new ASCII"
    Columns("A:D").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

    For i = 2 To 27
        Range("B" & i) = Chr(i + 63)
        Range("C" & i) = i + 63
        Range("A" & i) = Int((5 - (-5) + 1) * Rnd + (-5))
        Range("D" & i).Formula = _
            "=CHAR(IF(C" & i & "+A" & i & "<65,91-(65-(C" & i & "+A" & i & "))," & _
            "IF(C" & i & "+A" & i & ">90,65+(C" & i & "+A" & i & "-91),C" & i & "+A" & i & ")))"
    Next i
    Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

This will generate the following

[image]

You can look at the formula in column D `new ASCII` which should be (*for cell D2*)

```
=CHAR(IF(C2+A2<65,91-(65-(C2+A2)),IF(C2+A2>90,65+(C2+A2-91),C2+A2)))
```